# What are TFS Build Controllers?

Tags: team-foundation-server

Do build controllers exist in TFS2017 or have they been replaced by pools?  If they have not been replaced by pools do they exist in TFS2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Microsoft TFS2017 Q&A](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v1-windows#qa) can point you in the right direction. As you stated build controllers, I assume you mean the XAML build controllers. These are still usable in TFS 2017, but [Microsoft recommends to migrate these](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/migrate-from-xaml-builds) .

So there are still build controllers and agents for XAML in TFS 2017, only a few extra config steps needed.

Comment: It is more than a recommendation to migrate: they are not available in VSTS nor in TFS 2018.

Comment: They actually backed down and are keeping to support xaml builds in TFS 2018 and 2019, but consider them 'deprecated'. Not sure if and when they will actually stop supporting them.